# How can I read and evaluate a binary file that stores a binary search tree travseral?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, binaryfiles, tree-traversal

I have a binary file and I want to evaluate if it has binary search tree and if it is height balanced. The struct is:

```
struct node {
int val;
char bal;
struct node *left;
struct node *right;
}
```

And it is stored in a preorder traversal. The char is supposed to be a binary pattern where at bit position zero, a 0-bit means that the right branch of the node is NULL. A 1-bit means that the right branch of the node is a non-NULL node.At bit position 1 (the second least significant bit position), a 0-bit means that the left branch of the node is NULL. A 1-bit means that the left branch of the node is a non-NULL. A binary value of 2 or 3 means there is a left child. A binary value of 1 or 3 means that there is a right child. I have an example txt representation of the binary file:

```
-2 3
-4 3
-5 0
-3 0
 2 3
 0 3
-1 0
 1 0
 5 1
 4 0
```

Where a 3 represents that a node has two children, 2 represents that a node only has a left child, 1 represents that the node only has a right child, and 0 is zero children. If I build the tree out (remembering that it is pre-order traversal), I get this:

```
          -2
        /      \ 
       -4        2
     /   \      /  \ 
    -5   -3    0     5
              /  \     \
             -1   1     4
```

This tree is not a binary search tree as 5 is greater than 4. But it is balanced. Given the actual binary file which is this (using xxd -b command):

```
0000000: 11111110 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000011 11111100  ......
0000006: 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000011 11111011 11111111  ......
000000c: 11111111 11111111 00000000 11111101 11111111 11111111  ......
0000012: 11111111 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
0000018: 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011  ......
000001e: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000 00000001  ......
0000024: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101 00000000  ......
000002a: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000100 00000000 00000000  ......
0000030: 00000000 00000000                                      ..
```

How can actually open the binary file and do this kind of evaluation ? where I can evaluate whether it is indeed a BST and if it is height balanced ? I am struggling to start simply because the input file is binary and I don't know how to get past that.

Comment: Have you searched "how to read a binary file in C"? Because the first step is to read the file into your data structures. Do research on that search, make an attempt to at least open the file and read it into your structures. If you hit any problems you can't solve then come back to show your code and ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: `A 1-bit means that the right branch of the node is a non-NULL node.` `A 1-bit means that the left branch of the node is a non-NULL.` So what does the "a 1 bit" mean? `A binary value of 2 or 3 means there is a left child.` `A binary value of 1 or 3 means that there is a right child.` `a 0-bit means that the right branch of the node is NULL` I do not understand. Could you try explaining once again in the possible most verbose and clear way in what format in what way the data is stored in the binary file? How to convert from the txt representation to a binary file?

Comment: @KamilCuk it refers to bit positions. A 0 in bit position zero means no children. A 1 would  mean there's right child. A 1-bit in bit position one means there's a left child. If both positions have 1 then the node has two children. Hence binary value of 1 means there's a right child. Binary value of two means there's a left child. Binary value of three means there's both. Does that make sense ? Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: You can use `fread` to read 5 bytes at a time. Each 5 bytes consists of 4 bytes for the value, and 1 byte for the child info. Assemble the value using shift `<<` and OR `|`. Note that the bytes from the file are in little-endian order. So the first byte of the file is the least-significant byte of the first value.

Comment: Using `xxd -b -c 5` will make it easier to see what's in the file.

Comment: `it refers to bit positions` which byte? Every byte? Each byte represents a separate value? Or are the bytes somehow composed together? But you explain bits at position 0 and 1. So what does `11111110` mean? What do bit positions at 7 to 3 mean? What do the bits between mark `<mark>111111<mark>10` mean? @user3386109 I wonder, did you deduce it? It would make most sense - 4 bytes represent a the value inside the leaf encoded in little endian in twos complement. Then 1 byte represents the flags OP is explaining.

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I deduced it. I've gotten pretty good at reading the binary representation of twos complement over the years. 11111110 is -2, the next three bytes are just sign extension from the first byte, and 00000011 is 3. That matches the first line (`-2 3`) of the text that OP posted.  If the OP had requested that `xxd` display 5 bytes per line, instead of the default 6, it would be much easier to see the pattern.